# Text in a div that has a opacity of 0.5

Tags: css, html, opacity

I have a div container with text inside it.

The problem is I have the container set to have a opacity of 0.5 and I want the text to be at opacity of 1, but it can't exceed 0.5 because of the div.

I each made it so "p" was set to opacity of 1.0 in the stylesheet, but that still doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us your CSS/HTML?

Comment: To be clear: are you after having a div with ambiguous styles on it (any number of borders/outlines/backgrounds/etc), and would like to have everything *except* the text be 50% transparent, or are you using this for a **specific** case? If it's the latter, it would likely have a much easier solution.

Comment: is this what you're after? http://jsfiddle.net/TtSUD/1/

Answer (score 2):

Use [`rgba()`](http://deepubalan.com/blog/2010/03/29/rgba-vs-opacity-the-difference-explained/) instead on the container div to set the opacity, as the [`opacity`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparency) property is inherited by all children elements, even text nodes, meaning a descendant of any kind can't have a higher opacity than its parent

Comment: Maybe just to support IE (sigh...) http://kilianvalkhof.com/2010/css-xhtml/how-to-use-rgba-in-ie/

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your specific situation it's hard to say, but an element can only be as opaque as its parent.

One solution is to have another div that's a child of the div that acts like the one you have now.  Make the the second div `position: relative` and the transparent one `position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%;`, and it will be transparent in the background.  Other children of the main div can have their full opacity.  They need `position: relative` so the first div does not cover them.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/ngW9m/1/

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be working in all browsers i have:

http://css-tricks.com/non-transparent-elements-inside-transparent-elements/

Comment: sorry this is wrong example and not like the situation as explained in question.
if you see in firebug.
you will notice second h2 tag is outside second div.

Comment: i beg to differ -- The problem is I have the container set to have a opacity of 0.5 and I want the text to be at opacity of 1 ...